# Does this function have a root on this interval? Answer using limits

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a true or false question: the equation $x^{10} - 10\,x^{2} + 5$ has a root in the interval $(0,2)$.
My first guess was no, because I calculated the limit when $x\rightarrow0$ and then when $x\rightarrow2$, but when I graphed it it actually had two roots there. How could I answer the question mathematically? I mean, I don't want to try for different values of x.
I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: A easy to see, nice value is $x=1$.

Comment: Did you know any calculus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f (x )=x^{10}-10x^2+5$.

$f $ is continuous at $[0,2] $

$$f (0)=5>0$$
$$f (1)=-4 <0$$
$$f (2)=1024-40+5>0$$
thus by IVT,
there is a root in $(0,1) $ and a root in $(1,2) $.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about that theorem.

Comment: Minor grammar lesson:  a root lies *in*, not *at* an interval.  English is a funny language.  If you say "I'm in the hospital," it usually means you're sick; if you say "I'm at the hospital," is usually means you're visiting someone else who is sick.

Comment: @BarryCipra Your english is fine but Arabic is better for me.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima, your English is a whole let better than my Arabic!

Comment: @BarryCipra Choukrane. it means thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common type of problem in a first semester calculus course. Do you know about the Intermediate Value Theorem? Can you see how to apply it?

Comment: I am on my first semester, indeed. And no, I'd never heard of it, but I've read about it now. Thanks a lot! I understand how to do it, as it says on the other answer I got.